# Add certain results in a foreach to a shared container element

Tags: php

I'm struggling to verbalise this question, but hopefully I can demonstrate it:

I wish for certain results in a foreach loop to be grouped together in a container in the front-end.

So, if, for example, I have a foreach loop running through an array of car names and colours:

```
foreach($cars as $car){
 echo '<h1>'.$car->name.'</h1>';
 echo '<p>'.$car->colour.'</p><br/>';
}
```

It may give me:

```
<h1>Car1</h1>
<p>Blue</p><br/>

<h1>Car2</h1>
<p>Blue</p><br/>

<h1>Car3</h1>
<p>Red</p><br/>
```

However I need to group results with the same colour into a container div, so the output looks like:

```
<div class="blue">
 <h1>Car1</h1>
 <p>Blue</p><br/>

 <h1>Car2</h1>
 <p>Blue</p><br/>
</div>

<h1>Car3</h1>
<p>Red</p><br/>
```

Because the container div is technically outside of each loop I'm not sure how I can get it in there without using front-end script (i.e. javascript), but I'm hoping there's a way… any ideas? Perhaps even a way to identify the first of a type and the last of a type - but that's the closest I can get to a theory, let a lone a solution.

Edit: It appears there was some misunderstanding over the question. I wasn't looking to programatically group within the foreach, simply 'wrap' pre-grouped items.

Comment: do you have predefined list of colors ( eg. only blue, red and yellow)  or it can be any color?

Comment: I may have shot myself in the foot by oversimplifying my example data - but in short it could be any colour.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-dimensional array to build your data structure, then loop through the array to display your output.

Something like this:

```
$mycars = array();
foreach($cars as $car){
    $mycars[$car->colour][] = $car;
}
```

Now you have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Blue] => Array
        (
            [0] => {Car1Object}
            [1] => {Car2Object}
        )

    [Red] => Array
        (
            [0] => {Car3Object}
        )

)
```

Now loop through that array to display your output:

```
foreach($mycars as $colour => $cars) {
    echo "<div class='$colour'>";
    foreach($cars as $car) {
        echo "<h1>{$car->name}</h1>";
        echo "<p>{$car->colour}</p>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

And you get...

```
<div class='Blue'>
    <h1>Car1</h1>
    <p>Blue</p>
    <h1>Car2</h1>
    <p>Blue</p>
</div>
<div class='Red'>
    <h1>Car3</h1>
    <p>Red</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm - I have a feeling that this won't apply to my actual dataset, even though it;s a great answer based on my (perhaps oversimplified) example. I'll have to double check.

Comment: Then let us know how your actual dataset differs from your example. The above code allows for any number of cars or colors, nothing is pre-defined.

Comment: I may just post the real dataset. However the primary difference is that there's more than just a name and colour; each result has a whole set of data, so sticking with the above example there might also be a manufacturer, year, list of previous owners (separate object) etc. However that's not to say your answer won't apply - it looks very positive and may do just the trick.

Comment: Ok see my updated answer, particularly `$mycars[$car->colour][] = $car;` That's sticking the entire `$car` object in the array, so that when you loop through the array to display your output you can access any attribute like `$car->manufacturer`.

Comment: Incidentally my biggest concern is how it might effect the ordering of the results, as the order output by the database is carefully orchestrated at the query level. Is this an unfounded worry?

Comment: Ah, of course. Your updated answer makes it clearer in my head actually, I think you may have cracked it, and quick! Frustratingly I've just left the office and may not be able to look at this until after the weekend - I'll come back and flag as the correct answer once I can verify it!

Comment: OP would need to ensure the results are sorted (on color) before they enter the loop. Otherwise, he might end up with multiple divs for each color.

Comment: @gibberish eh? you could have "red" "blue" "yellow" "blue" "red" and you'll still only end up with one container div for each color. `$mycars[$car->colour][] = ...` is going to ensure that there is only one sub-array for each color.

Comment: Whups, sorry, you're right... didn't read closely enough. Had in mind a different algorithm and didn't see what was in front of me. Apologies.

Comment: In that case there would definitely be an issue, as there is a 'no colour' option that shouldn't be grouped. So the desired output could be (no colour single car),[blue cars],[red cars],(no colour single car),(no colour single car). So although I don't want multiple groups for each colour, I do need an exception that allows for 'no colour' (in this case '0' in the database) that shouldn't be grouped - as mentioned the order is extremely important to be preserved, all I want is for already grouped (by colour) cars to get a div around them - hopefully that's clearer, apologies for any confusion.

Comment: This answer fully answered your initial question. If you had a new, different code problem you should have posted a new question. Also, the answer you posted above will only work if your car colors are already grouped together. If you have cars "red" "blue" and then "red" again, the reds won't be grouped together.

Comment: They are grouped - but that wasn't part of my question. The grouping is handled as part of the query - I wasn't looking to programatically group (hence why the question was 'Add certain results in a foreach to a shared container element', not 'how to group results in a foreach'), I was looking to wrap the contents (I tried to make this clear later, it was a semantics issue).

The question didn't change, it just became more clear. Sometimes it's tricky to cover every angle. Appreciate your help regardless.